I need to implement onchain function into post API for blinks
    import {
  ActionPostResponse,
  ACTIONS_CORS_HEADERS,
  createPostResponse,
  ActionGetResponse,
  ActionPostRequest as BaseActionPostRequest,
} from "@solana/actions";
import {
  clusterApiUrl,
  Connection,
  PublicKey,
  Transaction,
  TransactionInstruction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import BN from "bn.js";
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import * as idl from "../../../../public/idl.json";
const connection = new anchor.web3.Connection(
  process.env.SOLANA_RPC! || anchor.web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"),
  "confirmed"
);


const programId = new PublicKey("AAkrLC6jXnorRDGFHAzEkoWjt1ZPaZ3wHx7Y8dnxn7Bt");

const keypair = 

// const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(connection, new anchor.Wallet(), {
//   preflightCommitment: "confirmed",
// });
// anchor.setProvider(provider);
const program = new anchor.Program(idl as anchor.Idl, programId, provider);

interface ActionPostRequest extends BaseActionPostRequest {
  submission_id: number;
}
const postHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    const body: ActionPostRequest = req.body;
    console.log(body);
    console.log(req.query);

    let submission_id = body.submission_id || req.query.submission_id;

   console.log(typeof(submission_id));

    let account: PublicKey;
    try {
      account = new PublicKey(body.account);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid "account" provided' });
    }
    const transaction = new Transaction();

    // const instruction = await program.methods
    //   .submitVote(new BN(submission_id))
    //   .accounts({
    //     user: account,
    //   })
    //   .instruction();

    // transaction.add(instruction);

    transaction.feePayer = account;
    transaction.recentBlockhash = (
      await connection.getLatestBlockhash()
    ).blockhash;

    // const payload: ActionPostResponse = await createPostResponse({
    //   fields: {
    //     transaction,
    //     message: `Submit a vote for submission ${submission_id}`,
    //   },
    // });

    // res.status(200).json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    let message = "An unknown error occurred";
    if (typeof err === "string") message = err;
    res.status(400).json({ error: message });
  }
};

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    await getHandler(req, res);
  } else if (req.method === "POST") {
    await postHandler(req, res);
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", ["GET", "POST"]);
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
  }
};

I an trying to implement a blink where i have to call the below function   I need to call submit Vote and the thing i need to take care is that the fee should be paid by user who is initiating the transaction so in that case how do i implement that function in the post request that's where i need help in
 use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use solana_program::entrypoint::ProgramResult;

declare_id!("AAkrLC6jXnorRDGFHAzEkoWjt1ZPaZ3wHx7Y8dnxn7Bt");

#[program]
pub mod voting_blinks {
    use super::*;

    pub fn submit_vote(ctx: Context<SubmitVote>, submission_id: u64) -> ProgramResult {
        // Emit an event
        emit!(VoteSubmitted {
            submission_id: submission_id,
            user_wallet: *ctx.accounts.user.key,
        });
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SubmitVote<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
}

#[event]
pub struct VoteSubmitted {
    pub submission_id: u64,
    pub user_wallet: Pubkey,
}

